# SearchView collapse animation in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, searchview

I have implemented `ActionBarSherlock` into my android project with no problems. I am now trying to add a `search widget` to the ActionBar and have done that successfully. Now, I would like to have the `Searchview` slide in from the right when expanded and out to the right when collapsed. I have two XML animations that I believe allow me to do that.

search_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

search_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

They are called form inside a SherlockFragmentActivity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    final Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.search_in);
    final Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.search_out);

    out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

     menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);

    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getText(R.string.searchHint));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {

            if(!queryTextFocused){
                searchView.startAnimation(out);
                searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            }
            else
                searchView.startAnimation(in);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}//end onCreateOptionsMenu
}
```

Here is how it looks now(since I can't post images yet...):

http://i194.photobucket.com/albums/z31/raitono/SearchviewCollapseProblem_zpsefee50e9.gif

The `search_in` animation works beautifully when the icon is tapped and the `search_out` works as well, when the back hardware key is pressed. I run into a snag when I try to collapse the Searchview through the small X though. It seems that the Searchview is collapsing before the animation is called and I don't know what to do about it. I've also tried `searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()` but that did no good. My guess is that I need to somehow intercept the call that is made when that X is pressed and do the animation first.

I am attempting to support devices as low as 2.3.5. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Is there anyway to detect when the small 'X' is tapped? That would solve my problem. I've been Googling but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Try to change your `search_out.xml` as `<translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="200%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />`

Comment: When I made this change, it acted the same way. The only noticeable difference is that the icon moved slower.

Comment: I recently changed how I did this. I used a custom view with an edit text in the action bar. I then was able to fix the problem with it not working by hitting the 'X', but now it doesn't work why I use the back button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about ActionBarSherlock. But in android SearchView widget you can use this

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        //Get the ID for the search bar LinearLayout
        int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
        //Get the search bar Linearlayout
        LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
        //Give the Linearlayout a transition animation.
        searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

Comment: I guess "android:id/search_bar" is not part of the public apis. Due to which searchBar is always null.